# How to import sensitive configuration in system?

Tags: magento2

```
<type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="sensitive" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="payment/test/password" xsi:type="string">1</item>
     </argument>
  </arguments>
</type>
```

let assume the above is configuration is defined as a sensitive configuration.

how we can import such configuration into the system?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue and did find it cumbersome too.

The process to export/import config data is documented at:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/configuration-management/import-configuration.html#

I did try this morning:
you may perform the following command in your dev environment for instance:

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento app:config:dump
```

then, the concept is to import the config  in the production environment next

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento app:config:import
```

Now, I imagine the question you really have is how is my encrypted value for the production environment come to life in my `app/etc/config.php??`

The solution we came up with was to use a yaml file that was containing the data specific to the environment used (dev, staging or production). Then, an orchestration process was pulling the values from this yaml file and modifying the file app/etc/config.php, Finally, we were able to use the import command.